# PHPExcel does not set the papersize correct in excel 2007

Tags: php, export, phpexcel, worksheet, page-setup

**SOLVED 

(Solution explained under the question)**

I am trying to change the page setup for a XLSX file with PHPExcel.
But whenever i change the papersize, it results in a USER defined size with the wrong width and height.

This is what i do:

```
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A3);
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

In the XLS file, it works correct.
But in the XLSX file not.

I already searched on google and on the forum but i could not find anything about it.
Am i doing something wrong?

I am testing in Libre Office (i also checked it on excel but it has the same problem)

The result of a XLSX file:
[image: This is the result]

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance!

**Solution:**

It was a libreOffice bug.
The problem for libre office is that it want a attribute for the printer settings. If it is not defined, it will automatically takes the printer settings.

Comment: What is it actually giving as the defined paper size in the xlsx file?

Comment: If i try to set a papersize and i look it up in the file it says 'user' with a 21 x 27 size

Comment: @JimOuwerkerk what did you actually do to fix it? I'm having the same problem at the moment.

Comment: never mind, got it, just moved my code to the bottom of my script, just before the save and email part as a trial and error but it worked.

Comment: well, actually nothing fixed it for me. I was testing it in libreoffice but it has to work on excel. The paper size was correct in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a libreOffice bug. The problem for libre office is that it want a attribute for the printer settings. If it is not defined, it will automatically takes the printer settings.